# How to deal with droplet issue with prayer?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, incontinence

I want to ask a common man question: if a person having droplets throughout the day, can he offer his prayer?
If not, then how to get rid of this thing to perform his prayer?

Comment: +1 good question, this may happen to many young or old people

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that is called [incontinence urinary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urinary_incontinence) (السلس البولي).
According to many fatwas, the person should do his wudu'u normally and don't care about that even if the droplets happen right after the wudu'u or during the prayer, his prayer is right.
sources :

- http://www.masrawy.com/Islameyat/Fatawy/Ebadat/2010/may/16/Incontinence.aspx
- http://ar.islamway.net/fatwa/28737
- http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=A&Id=119395

Allah knows better.

Comment: what the droplets are not of urination and of some other viscous material then what about that even in that he can offer his prayers study quran and Perform wudu`u ?
Thank you in advance for attending the question

Comment: According the [masrawy link](http://www.masrawy.com/Islameyat/Fatawy/Ebadat/2010/may/16/Incontinence.aspx) the incontinence can be about urination, sperm... >السّلس عند الفقهاء :ومعناه استرسال الخارج بدون اختيار من بول ، أو مذي ، أو منيّ ،أو ودي، أو غائط ، أو ريح ، وقد يطلق السّلس ، على : الخارج نفسه.

Comment: Can you please translate in English Thanks in Advance

Comment: I edited my comment above. Instead of translating the pages with google translate I'll give you another link in english, hoping it'll be clear that way : http://islamqa.info/en/ref/66074