# Tahaara and waswas

Tags: salat, wudu, taharah

Assalamualaykum,

I have a problem with severe waswasa. I have urinary incontinence. And I'm scared of touching things. When i go to the toilet and wash my bum and move my hand some water falls on the toilet seat and i wash it off with the Muslim shower but if it falls on the floor which gets wet and i step on it and walk in the house.
 Is where i stepped unclean?
 Is my toilet unclean?

Sometimes i have tummy problems and i think i got all the poop off but didn't and again the water falls and I'm always scared now of my house being unclean and the water drops that splatter from the floor result in me washing myself in the shower.
 What do i do?

I'm worried about using toilets at school in case a non Muslim used it before and the wetness that comes onto me is najis. I generally wash myself many times in the day in the shower. In regards to the incontinence, when i wash myself after urinating and stand up or I'm in the shower i feel like a drop of pee may have come out because i get that feeling which makes me panic as I'm wet and i don't know if it transferred anywhere else or how to shower these days due to being scared of drops of pee going over me or my towel which i use for my body and hair.

Please help me because i spend at least 30 mins in the toilet before wudu which is starting to annoy me and those i pray with and I'm just so stressed because of this i really need your help.

Jazakallah khair.

Comment: Jazakallah, what about the water that falls from your hand after washing the provate parts? I step on this water and walk in the house and now i realise that my house may be dirty and i am worried about this. I dont lile stepping out of my shower in fear pf stepping on najis water please help in this as well. If some water falls off my hand on the toilet seat i wadh it with the muslim shower but the water falls on the floor and i step on that with my shoes. Is my toilet floor unclean, and if so walkong in the house does it make my house floor uncleean too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does dripping urine break Wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2955/11938)

Answer (score 1):

Well i think i can't give you an answer about the waswas part of your statement. 
But I'll try to give you a hopefully helpful hint for the tahara Issue (at least wudu and ghusl):

First you should know that wudu and ghusl are in first place some kind of ritual washings, so doing it doesn't mean you will be clean from a hygienic PoV.
So using used water is allowed in most madhabs (See details [Is it permissible to re-use the water that has been already used [by myself] for ablution?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26139/is-it-permissible-to-re-use-the-water-that-has-been-already-used-by-myself-for/26141#26141)) and it doesn't make neither the prayer nor wudu/ghusl invalid!

The only impurities that may afford doing wudu are stated in [Which things break the wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11103/which-things-break-the-wudu)?, for ghusl you may add intercourse, janabah, menstruation, postpartum period... Anything else wouldn't count as najis. And even when it comes to najassa and water scholars say that if there is only a few najassa commpared to the volume of water this water is considered as clean for ghusl/wudu with differences in the madahib.

On the other Hand if you did ghusl one of the last Sunan of it is [washing the feet](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/104). So you should do it before stepping out of the shower/tub.

And for many situation where human is not able to control the functionality of his body there are exceptions for example: incontinence ... (see also [If you have continuous gas during prayer, can you purposely let it out?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28683/if-you-have-continuous-gas-during-prayer-can-you-purposely-let-it-out)?)

Now you should do your best to remove anything najis from your clothes, and your body (but for example if you are under a shower you may have done it when the water passes the place which have been touched by najasa, if needed you should ub it away) and don't step in it. If you do so then your only problem may be the waswas!

Further more you may take a look at:
[A person having Droplet Issue](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7050/a-person-having-droplet-issue/7052)
[Is prayer acceptable if my wudhu breaks?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10989/is-prayer-acceptable-if-my-wudhu-breaks)
[Does dripping urine break Wudu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2955/does-dripping-urine-break-wudu)

I hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

To actually answer your question, the water that falls on the floor from doing Istinja is not impure, because you can't be 100% sure it's impure water. The only way something becomes impure is if you're 100% sure it became impure by seeing it with your eyes.

Also, if you suffer from a medical condition, you just need to wash the area and make wudu before each prayer. Do not think about urine getting on your clothes and contaminating other things. If it's not a medical condition and you THINK you suffer from urinary inconsistency, it could just be in your head--which is a form of waswas and if this is the case than you should completely ignore this doubt unless you are 100% sure urine came out.

Do not look for answers online from forms or bloggers. I only say this because I too suffer from severe OCD and waswas to the point where I've had to seek help from a scholar. The first thing I was told was to not look for answers online because most people aren't aware of fiqhi matters and also because someone suffering with OCD and waswasa needs reassurance to their own thoughts and questions.

The basic principal that is helping me is:  nothing is impure until you are 100% sure it's impure. I never went to a doctor but I still feel I suffer from urinary inconsistency. When I think about it, I always feel like it's dripping when I'm showering or when I cough or laugh or even pray. When I forget about it or when my waswasa is not as strong at that particular time I do not feel anything came out. That's why I stated above that it could just be in your head. Again, unless you are 100% sure, you have to do your best to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

if you feel this way, you're not the only one. I actually experience the same stuff as well. But I have been diagnosed with OCD (obsessive compulsive disorder), which means that a person is occupied with obsessive thoughts, which require him or her perform compulsions to get rid of the thoughts. In my case, I have regular obsessive thoughts about cleanliness , my wuzu etc. I constantly feel uncomfortable and unclean even on the slightest impurity, and i feel as if I have to perform wudu all the time, wash my private parts extra well in order to perform prayer, etc. I understand what you go through, and I want to request you to discuss this with an adult, or your parents or any older sibling. They may be able to help you. Or you may be subject to OCD. It is a possibility, but not a certainty. Because only people with this disorder suffer from the thoughts and doubts you just described above. And as for your questions about taharah, almost all of them have been answered above. May Allah bless us all.